# On monomial and $\Omega^d$-finite algebras

Tags: rt.representation-theory, homological-algebra, gap

Let $Q$ be a finite quiver and $I$ a monomial admissible ideal of the path algebra $KQ$ for a field $K$. Then an algebra $A=KQ/I$ is called a monomial algebra.
It is well known that monomial algebras have the property that for any map $f : P_1 \rightarrow P_0$ between projective modules one has $ker(f) \in add(M)$ for some fixed finite dimensional module $M$ (independet of $f$). This means that monomial algebras are $\Omega^2$-finite. Here an algebra being $\Omega^d$-finite for some $d \geq 1$ means that there are only finitely many indecomposable summands in total of modules of the form $\Omega^d(N)$ for any module $N$ up to isomorphism.

> Question 1: Is there an easy proof for monomial algebras being $\Omega^2$-finite that avoids ugly computations (and is easy to remember)?
>
> Question 2: Can this result about monomial algebras be generalised to some class of quiver algebras that are $\Omega^d$-finite for $d \geq 3$? (I am not really aware of nice classes of algebras that are $\Omega^d$-finite for $d \geq 3$ and not for smaller $d$, any examples are welcome)
>
> Question 3: Can it be checked via QPA whether a given quiver algebra is $\Omega^d$-finite for some $d \geq 1$ (at least for special cases like quadratic algebras)? For example for $d=2$ it reduces to the problem of describing all (indecomposable summands of ) kernels between maps of projective modules $P_1 \rightarrow P_0$.